# wordpress portfolio only one image displaying

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and want to set up a portfolio page. When I add portfolio items, Only one image will ever show up in the grid. I am using the dante theme and every page I try is the same. If I make a new page with the portfolio element in swift page builder I get the same result, only one image displayed.

Is there anything I am not doing right?

Answer (score 0):

The picture was too wide at 700+ pixels.